# Attempting to allow SFTP connection to a preconfigured Linode

Tags: ubuntu, linode

I'm attempting to allow an SFTP connection to a preconfigured Linode. It's running Ubuntu 12.04. I was entirely Linux green until six weeks ago, but I've been learning as I go.

I left the station the Linode was setup on, and learned the iptables were configured to only allow connections from specific IPs.

I still have Linode Shell access, but I'm using a Verizon Jetpack and my IP is changing pretty regularly. I also don't want to create a security hole, and it feels like I'm playing with fire here.

I attempted a:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
```

to try and allow SSH/SFTP access from all IPS but, I still get a timeout error in Filezilla using the linode IP and same login info as I did before.

I'm unsure the best course of action, as I'd prefer to tread lightly in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) by default, so I wouldn't try modifying `iptables` rules unless you have to.

I use a `limit` rule to allow OpenSSH, since people will constantly try to attack a Linode on the public internet. So this would probably do the trick:

```
$ sudo ufw limit OpenSSH
```